# url dispatch using backbone.js

Tags: django, backbone.js

I m developing an app in django and am using backbone.js. The urls are routed using a backbone router. My HTML is in one static page, when I click a link eg `href="/user/home"`, a page is loaded and if I  refresh the browser (send an http request) with the url, I get error 404 since the django urls don't have that url.

I have a senario where i'm using facebook (django_facebook) to login and whenever I click the link Facebook sign in, I get a blank page (just the way any other invalid url would do because of this *splats -- `{"*action" : "defaultRoute"}` see code below), and when I refresh the browser the it works (opens fb tab for login.) since i have`url(r'^facebook/', include('django_facebook.urls'))`, in URLS.PY.

My issue is how to click the link and have fb tab or pop-up window open since in this case its not working, I have to hit the url in the browser for it to work.

backbone.js router

```
Api.Routers.MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    ":user/messages/:action/:target": "messagesAction",
    ":user/challenge/:action/:target" : "gameScores",
    ":user/challenge/:action/:target/:bet" : "challengeResult",
    ":user/challenge/:action": "challengeAction",
    ":user/:action" : "userAction",
    ":user/friends/:action/:target" : "friendsAction",
    "*action" : "defaultRoute"
},
messagesAction: function (user, action, target) {
    myScrollAction = action;
    conversationAction (action);
    //HIGHTLIGHT FOOT NAV
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $("#nav-messages").parents("li").addClass("selected");

    $(".message-friend-name").html(target.replace(/%20/g, " "))
},
challengeResult: function (user, action, target, bet) {
    defaultRouterAction (action);
    myScrollAction = action;
    ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: isn't backbone route supposed to be appended after hash (#)? For me it seems the routing doesn't work at all.

Comment: @migajek only in browsers that don't support the HTML5 history object (IE8 & IE9 I'm looking at you)

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you're asking two questions here.

The first question involves the fact that you have routes in your Backbone router that your Django App does not have.

So when the router takes over it actually pushes new history into your browser's history stack (unless you're in IE8 & 9 when it uses a hash fragment).  This means that your browser, when you hit reload is going to request that resource from the server.

In order to prevent 404s from happening you either will have to not use the history object or make sure all the routes that exist in your Backbone router also are mirrored in your Django URL configuration.

The second question you have is around using Facebook login.  You should separate this part of the question and re-ask it since it's also about the Django plugin you're using and you'll get much better traction if you do that.